# Error in Web.EnsureUser(user) :- User Not Found

Tags: development, 2013, error, spuser

Hey Friends I am trying to develop a web part in that I am fetching the user name.

But doing this I am getting the error that `User cannot be found`.

But the main thing is that in the line where I am getting this error has the same code written in the above line and it is passed through that and gives me the error in the bellow line.
Code :

```
string pc = ddlPrincipleConsultant.SelectedItem.Text;
string associateconsultant = "";
string domain = System.Environment.UserDomainName;
string authoby = ddltravelcost.SelectedItem.Text;
SPUser user = web.EnsureUser(pc); //It gives me proper user name    
SPUser authorizedby = web.EnsureUser(authoby);// Here I get the error
```

Here is the screenshot of the error.

[image: Screenshot for the above problem]

And I also tried with below code.

```
SPUser user = web.AllUsers[pc];
SPUser authorizedby = web.AllUsers[authoby];
```

But in this it gives me error in both. Both statement do not find the users.

Please Help me to solve this prolem..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include the Domain name in EnsureUser - Domain\Username

Comment: **Yes it Worked**. But I have got the user name in first statement and in the second statement it throws an error. What is the reason of it..???

Comment: EnsureUser will look if the user is in SP, or, if the user hasn't accessed SP, will go to Active Directory to look up the user. It may be that in one of those two scenarios the domain isn't required? Or perhaps if the user has direct permissions to SP vs permissions based on membership in an AD group?

Comment: Yes it is true but if I am getting all my user in DDL from the Active Directory then also it is not finding users. But for the first line it find the user. and in second line it gave me error. You can see in screenshot.

Comment: I want to know why this happened?? What is the reason behind this that first time it find the user and the second time it gave error.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same error. I noticed that the error occurs when the username has "." like in your screenshot. To be safe, you need to get the encoded claim value for the user and pass that into the EnsureUser method. Look these articles:

1. [First](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2013/02/03/what-you-need-to-know-about-using-ensureuser-in-claims-based-web-apps-in-sharepoint-2010-and-sharepoint-2013.aspx);
2. [Second](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/programmatically-converting-login-name-claim/).

Or you can just add `i:0#.f|myprovider|` to the username so it looks like `i:0#.f|myprovider|myuser` and pass the result into EnsureUser. In my case "myprovider" is the name of my custom membership provider.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct, probably the problem is somewhere else. Meanwhile, could you try this approach?

```
SPUser user = null;
SPUser authorizedby = null;
using (_web = web.Site.OpenWeb(web.ID))
{
    user = _web.EnsureUser(pc); 
}
using (_web = web.Site.OpenWeb(web.ID))
{
    authorizedby = _web.EnsureUser(authoby); 
}
```

This code is obviously over verbose, but maybe it will works.

Comment: No this solution not worked.

Comment: Did you check that pc and authoby strings are really equal? What would happen if you try to Ensure authoby string first?

Comment: they both the string values comes from the DropDownList. In that list I am storing my Application Users. Which are created by me. And that users, I am storing in Strings `pc` and `authoby`.

Comment: I have just tested with the same user in both the DDL list. but user can select different users. and the same error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I had to convert a possible `Claims Authentication` name format back to DOMAIN\USER format to run `EnsureUser`. Seems `EnsureUser` will work with the claims format for existing users that have accessed the site, but not new users.

This code sample gets the email address for a user by first checking if the provided name is in claim format and converts it to DOMAIN\USER format:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims;
...

string emailAddress = string.Empty;
string userLogin = userName;
if (SPClaimProviderManager.IsEncodedClaim(userName))
{
  userLogin = SPClaimProviderManager.Local.ConvertClaimToIdentifier(userName);
}

SPUser user = web.EnsureUser(userLogin);
if (user != null)
{
  emailAddress = user.Email;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with below code. It will worked properly.

```
SPUser u = SPContext.Current.Web.Users[username];
```