# web.EnsureUser(encUserName) throwing Exception - User Not Found

Tags: sharepoint-server, spuser

I found this [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62555/error-in-web-ensureuseruser-user-not-found) for reference but I am not getting the solution that I want. I have created a custom web part and in that, I have written

web.EnsureUser(userloginname);

It works perfectly for the user which is in the SharePoint site. But it won't work for some of the users(users which do not access the site). I have given permission to everyone in the Site.

Comment: How are you getting the value for userloginname and what value is in this variable (example) ?

Comment: this is the sample example of user login name i:0#.w|testsp2016\testuser2. I have given permission to everyone but for some of the user it throwing an error.